# Is there a way to register "Comments" model (filtered by post) inside "Posts/SomePost in Django administration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to to make each post (inside admin) have a "Comments" like field that are specific to that post instead of having "Comments" as a separate section from "Posts". Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

you must use InlineModelAdmin class to make any post have related comments inside it.

for example use in admin.py like this :

```
    class CommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Comment
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

and add this attrebute to the PostAdmin class in your admin.py :

```
    class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         inlines = [CommentInline]
```

for more information read this :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Comment: But is it possible to place the "inlines= [CommentInline]" inside not just "Posts" but the corresponding post that contains those comments? - as in - Posts/1 etc.